# How do I apply a slider effect to the Qi widget "interactive links" for elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using the "Interactive Links" widget from "Qi Addons for ELEMENTOR" for my wordpress website. I found the widget with this image slider effect (where the image slides from left to right over the image before while hovering the text) on the Qi website in the fourth section in (I think) the same widget: https://qodeinteractive.com/qi-addons-for-elementor/
and would like to have the same effect on my website in combination with the possibilities offered by the "interactive links" widget, but I couldn't find a way to set this in the settings.

So now my question is, am I mistaken and is this a different widget? If so, which one?
And if it is the same widget, how do I apply this effect with code (I'm a total newbie, but I am willing to try).

Thanks a lot already!

[image: Hovering the first title]
[image: Slider animation when hovering the second title]
[image: Completed animation while still hovering the second title]